# How to put anchor tags side by side?

Tags: html, css

Im having an issue trying to get a phone number link and an email link side by side, in my navbar.

This is from an html theme, which i am customizing. I am fairly new at coding so I am majorly stuck. I dont have the email anchor tag in there, ive just been copying and pasting the same anchor tag to try and figure out how to do this.

Its confusing, because as you scroll down, it is desinged to invert the color of the Navbar. Thats why you see two of the same anchor tag. Its the phone number in white, then black, as you scroll down.

Im just trying to get another anchor tag (an email link) to the right of this tag.

Hope thats ot too confusing. Thanks!

```
<header class="header header-fixed header-fixed-on-mobile header-transparent" data-bkg-threshold="100">
            <div class="header-inner">
                <div class="row nav-bar">
                    <div class="column width-12 nav-bar-inner">
                        <div class="logo width-12">
                            <div class="logo-inner">
                                <a href="tel:1-530-680-8255"  style="color:grey">1-530-680-8255</a>
                                <a href="tel:1-530-680-8255"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>1-530-680-8255</a>



                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by this, if I run the code, it shows the 2 numbers side by side. What do you want it to be. Please show an image or describe. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This code should make it sit next to each other. Display:inline-block does that. It makes it sit inline

```html
<a href="tel:1-530-680-8255"  style="color:grey; display:inline-block">1-530-680- 
     8255</a>
      <a href="tel:1-530-680-8255"><i class="fas fa-phone" style="display:inline-block"> 
       </i>1-530-680-8255</a>
```

Comment: actually it doesnt seem to be changing it. I know this works, but I think there is something in the header and navbar that is causing this problem. Most of the attemts i make just put it right on top of itself, duplicating. I was thinking, is it because the div it is inside of too small? To small to accomodate two anchor tags side by side? Idk. Im stumped